# how do i resolve this when am deploying solidity on vs code

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain, ico

project:/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/price/IncreasingPriceCrowdsale.sol:49:5: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
function finalRate() public view returns (uint256) {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
project:/contracts/KATCrowdsale.sol:12:5: The previous declaration is here:
uint256 public finalRate = 10000;
^------------------------------^
,project:/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/price/IncreasingPriceCrowdsale.sol:42:5: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
function initialRate() public view returns (uint256) {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
project:/contracts/KATCrowdsale.sol:11:5: The previous declaration is here:
uint256 public constant initialRate = 1000000;
^-------------------------------------------^
,project:/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/validation/TimedCrowdsale.sol:56:5: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
function closingTime() public view returns (uint256) {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
project:/contracts/KATCrowdsale.sol:14:5: The previous declaration is here:
uint256 public closingTime =  1655053529;
^--------------------------------------^
,project:/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/crowdsale/validation/TimedCrowdsale.sol:49:5: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
function openingTime() public view returns (uint256) {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
project:/contracts/KATCrowdsale.sol:13:5: The previous declaration is here:
uint256 public openingTime = 1649783129;
^-------------------------------------^
,project:/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol:51:5: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
project:/contracts/KAToken.sol:11:5: The previous declaration is here:
uint256 public constant  decimals = 18;
^------------------------------------^
,project:/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol:27:5: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
function name() public view returns (string memory) {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
project:/contracts/KAToken.sol:10:5: The previous declaration is here:
string public constant name = "Offecial Kick Ass Token";
^-----------------------------------------------------^
,project:/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol:35:5: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
project:/contracts/KAToken.sol:9:5: The previous declaration is here:
string public constant symbol = "OKAT";
^------------------------------------^

Comment: Looks like you are declaring variables that already exist in your files.  Uploading your solidity code will help us solve your issue better.

Comment: I already solved it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do remove the calls from the general contract and put them inside the constructor then fill the parameters inside the deployment codes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).